# Capturing type in Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this route in my Sinatra app:

```
post ':type/new' do
  data = JSON.parse request.body.read
  id = $database.add_instance(params[:type], data['content'])
  id.to_json
end
```

Now when I post to `/wombat/new` it returns a 404, recommending that I add `post '/wombat/new'` to my routes.

Why isn't it matching that route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
post '/:type/new' do
  ...
```

(note the leading `/`).

Comment: Saw this just after you posted, sad times.